# Is there any way to make Console prompt for authentication to logs the user isn't authorised to?

Tags: mojave, logs, administrator, console

If I try to access *system.log* from my non-admin account I get the message *"Unable to read the file"*

Is there any way to make *Console.app* prompt for administrator credentials to view logs the user isn't authorised to as happens elsewhere in the GUI?

[image: Console]

Presumably the message is because I'm not authorised:

```
A1398% ls -la /private/var/log/system.log
-rw-r-----  1 root  admin  1807993 Jan 23 16:14 /private/var/log/system.log
```

I know `sudo /Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/MacOS/Console` will open *Console.app* with sufficient rights but it is rather inconvenient.

Comment: It had been some time for me, but what about `sudo open -a Console` (could be that it was `-A`)?  Does that still work?  If so, it would at least shorten the command line.

Comment: @Phoenix - `sudo open -a Console` opens Console but despite the `sudo` only as current user so the *system.log* is unavailable.

Comment: Ah, ok.  As stated: It was some time ago (~3--4 years) since I last did something with `open` and currently not even run macOS any more.  Thanks for testing it though. :-)

Comment: @Phoenix - would have been good - I was optimistic :-)

Comment: The command path in Catalina is now `/System/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/MacOS/Console`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console.app is not designed to prompt for credentials.

If you don't want to type the command every time or you don't want to remember it you have two similar choices:

Create a simple bash script or a nice automation with Automator and then you can place it everywhere you want.